# Acute angles in non-convex n-gon?

Tags: geometry, polygons, angle

What is the maximum amount of acute angles in a non-convex non-overlapping n-gon?
I have figured out a lower and upper limit (using angle sum), but they aren't helpful at all and get worse as n increases.
Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: You should give your bounds so that people know what you already know.

Comment: I can get at least n/2 acute angles and at max n-1.

Comment: Then your lower bound is optimal.